# code organisation

Tags: php

SO far, from my experience, in login scripts, I have to come to realize that the login form
should be in the same script with the validation functions/code.

I mean the form action of the form and the validation will be in the same script.
But what about when the user has checked also the "remember me" option?

Do you think that the user should be redirected to a different page(member's page)?

Or again, in one page?
I mean one page in the first scenario, 2 pages in the second scenario.

Comment: There are many (myself included) who believe that form and code should be in different files unless we 're talking about a weekend project or something similarly small.

Comment: read about [MVC architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Answer (score 3):

It's considered bad practice to code the form in the login script. Consider the scenario when a designer and a developer work togheter for redesigning the website. They can't both work on the same file at the same time.
You should separate the code (business logic) from the presentation (html). You should have a script php that handles the auth process and the html form in a separate file.

Regarding "remember me" functionality, if the use has logged in using the login form, and checked the "remember me" checkbox, next time he visits the site, he should automatically be authenticated and redirected to the members page

Comment: So, in order to make things more clear, I am going to talk more abstract. Are we talking about 3 pages here? One of the form, one for auth code and a different for the member section-sorry, I was confused

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou it all depends on your application. But yes, you can do it that way if your website consists only in a login form and a page dedicated for registered users

Comment: Μy app has more than than these 2 pages, but I think i am going to follow what you suiggest

Comment: One last thin-with 3 pages, are they going to be problems with performance/speed?

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou it all depends on what your site does and the traffic. If it's only authenticating the user and listing some data from the db then performance shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Ok. suppose that my site has a lot of traffic(in the future maybe)...i n such a case would you put all the code in one page(form,validation,member's code)...would you do it?

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou Never. Performance drop is insignificant when including multiple files vs coding all in one page. you should never bother with this. Always design you app so it is modular and easy to maintain and aim for code reuse.

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou please accept the answer if it has helped you. Thanks